# What does "breaks down" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Vincent: You just can't walk into a restaurant, roll a joint and start
> puffin' away. I mean, they want you to smoke in your home or  certain
> designated places.
>
> Jules: Those are hash bars?
>
> Vincent: Yeah. It **breaks down** like this. It's legal to buy it. It's
> legal  to own it.

What does "breaks down" mean?

Source: Pulp Fiction 1994

Comment: Please include your own research in your post. This seems answerable with a dictionary search: [break down 3. phrasal verb
To break down something such as an idea or statement means to separate it into smaller parts in order to make it easier to understand or deal with. (Collins)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/break-down). Please see [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Breaks down” in this context is to “reduce the argument to its logical components”.